How do I write a promise chain with forks that depend on conditions?
I'm looking for a way to create a promise chain that has forks. By "forks" I mean the chain could go in two or more different directions depending on some condition. For example:
getIndexes(searchString).then(indexes => {
  if (indexes.length) return searchByIndex(indexes, 1, 5);
  else return searchAllRecords(searchString);
}.then(records => {
  // if searched all records
  return createIndexes(records, searchString);
  // else
  return records;
}).then( // how to handle multiple forks

As you can see, there are conditions in each then block and depending on the condition, it will return something different to the next then block by calling different functions. So we don't know what each then block will receive as it depends on the outcomes of the previous conditions, and we have to do checks to see how it should be handled. This doesn't seem ideal. What is the best way to build a promise chain when it contains forks in the flow?

FYI: this may be easier to read using async/await syntax

Use nesting, not a simple chain:
getIndexes(searchString).then(indexes => {
  if (indexes.length) {
    return searchByIndex(indexes, 1, 5);
  } else {
    return searchAllRecords(searchString).then(records => {
      // we searched all records
      return createIndexes(records, searchString);
    });
  }
}).then(…

